# Can I add icons to the sound menu?

Tags: banshee, indicator-sound

I would like to add a shuffle and a repeat button (for banshee, if that matters at all) in the sound menu 
Is it possible to add custom buttons there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These buttons are hard coded, so I would suggest you report a bug and tag it as wish-list for indicator-sound.

Comment: thanks - i'll do that as soon as i get home. even though i don't think they will ever implement it, it would be too ugly for them to include it.